# Amazon S3 bucket convert filename to keyname

Tags: amazon-s3

In my application I am saving files on amazon S3 bucket.
I wanted to use the filename as the key. 
But I am keep getting error on file name that contain characters which are not English characters or dots. Even space causes an exception. I tried to use Base64 on the filename but even '=' is problematic.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: You could use modified base64 where you substitute for illegal characters like = .

Comment: Please be more specific about the exact error you are getting.  Object keys can contain any valid utf-8 character, although some characters like space (ASCII 32) need to be url-escaped ("percent-encoded"), e.g. space becomes `%20` and `+` becomes `%2B`.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot 
When I tried to put a key named with%20space.txt I got:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch;

Comment: Which SDK and version are you using, here?  Show your code, too?  S3 does have some quirks related to the handling of spaces (the original designers made some invalid assumptions that are now presumably too entrenched to be fixed and must instead be worked around) but if an SDK is generating bad signatures, that's more than a quirk.  Try to get your hands on the actual HTTP response body from that error -- it should reveal what you're doing compared to what S3 assumes you're doing.